# Hybris Backoffice Maximum Upload Size

Tags: upload, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am trying to upload a media file to its container.
Default value of maximum file size for uploading is 10 MB and it is defined at `ext-backoffice\backoffice\project.properties` like this :

```
# Constraint for maximum upload file size (in KB)
backoffice.fileUpload.maxSize=10000
```

How can i override this value?
After some research i found this [link](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002524449) . 
But sadly it does not work for me. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please add an error page which you see after the upload operation? I would like to read a stack trace. Also a print script with a browser window would be helpful.

Comment: @İlker Demirci, you can override property value in your local.properties file.

Comment: Can you add the solution you tried? Not everybody has access to the SAP pages.

Comment: Overriding # backoffice.fileUpload.maxSize=10000 on local.properties solved my problem. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of this property (or any property) on the **hAC** (if you are an admin). But the value will stay until the server is restarted

the best approach is to add the property backoffice.fileUpload.maxSize= the value you want on the local.properties so the server read it every time it starts